# C++: program returns different JSON result than if url is accessed manually

Tags: c++, json, getjson

I'm working on a project manipulating a roomba. The RooWifi microcontroller I'm using writes the sensor data to a json file every so often, and I'm trying to fetch the json, parse it, and base my actions off of the output.

I'm having an issue grabbing data from a json at a URL. The file is at an address, say

```
http://10.0.0.1/roomba.json
```

and I can manually enter the address into Chrome and see the data. However, when I grab the json file programmatically, data values are zero.

The format of the json, and how I see it in Chrome, is:

```
{
 "response": { 
       "r13": {
                "name": "Angle",
                "value": "0"
              },
       "r14": {
                "name": "Charging State",
                "value": "4" 
              },
       "r18": {
                "name": "Charge",
                "value": "863"
              },
       "r19": {
                "name": "Capacity",
                "value": "1618"
              }
            }
}
```

What is returned programmatically is:

```
{
 "response": { 
       "r13": {
                "name": "Angle",
                "value": "0"
              },
       "r14": {
                "name": "Charging State",
                "value": "0" 
              },
       "r18": {
                "name": "Charge",
                "value": "0"
              },
       "r19": {
                "name": "Capacity",
                "value": "0"
              }
            }
}
```

I'm using Qt Creator and c++. I'm not very proficient at c++ and have never used Qt (the library functions are packaged with this), so I thought my first attempt using the Qt json parser and url requests was just implemented incorrectly. I then copied the code from Evgeny at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13096222/2415349. His code retrieves the json file, but all of the 'values' are zero.

I've tried putting the fetch/parse functions in a loop, but each time the same thing is returned.

What is odd is that I can however get the json file with populated values in python using the json and urllib2 libraries.

Can anyone shed any light as to why this is occurring? I've only ever parsed files that are on my machine. Is the request only getting something like the default json, for when the roomba is turned off? Do my computer or browser need to be set up a certain way (Im using Mac OSX 10.9.4).

EDIT: This is the the code I've used from Evgeny's answer (get_http() is also used)

```
string get_http(const string &server,const string &path);
using namespace boost::property_tree;
stringstream temp;
temp << get_http("10.0.0.1","/roomba.json");
cout << "Original JSON:" << endl;
cout << temp.str();
cout << string(256,'*') << endl;
ptree root;
read_json(temp,root);
cout << "Printed as XML:" << endl;
write_xml(cout,root);
```

I'm seeing the output I mentioned above when temp.str() and root are printed to cout.

EDIT 2:

I've realized that the request is returning the same json. My original set up was to run the application, and watch the output the program was returning. I would then stop the application, and go to 10.0.0.1/roomba.json manually.

Does anyone have an idea why when then application is running that the json file is set to all zeros, but when it is not (but I am connected to the device) the json file outputs the data?

Comment: Might need to see your parsing code. Are you specifying types somewhere? As in types of data expected?

Comment: Which part of Evgeny's code shows zeros? If you just dump the HTTP stream do you have nonzero values? Or do the zeros appear once you parse the JSON?

Comment: I've edited the question with that specific part of his code. It is just returning the entire JSON as a string. His code only dumps the contents, I'm not attempting to extract specific sensor 'values' yet.